# Stacked Bar Chart with general update pattern d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I know there are a few posts out here and I've been trying really hard for several hours today and yesterday.
But I can not get the enter, update, exit to work in the most basic sense.

I've been trying to change an interactive bar plot that I made into a stacked bar plot.
This hasn't worked at all and I thought to try to get the simplest case to work from an example [here](https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_stacked_basicWide.html) instead.
However, even this I am not able to.
I don't understand why.

```
const margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 20, left: 50},
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
const svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

// Parse the Data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/data_stacked.csv").then( function(data) {

// List of subgroups = header of the csv files = soil condition here
const subgroups = data.columns.slice(1)

// List of groups = species here = value of the first column called group -> I show them on the X axis
const groups = data.map(d => (d.group))

// Add X axis
const x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(groups)
    .range([0, width])
    .padding([0.2])
svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0));

// Add Y axis
const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 60])
    .range([ height, 0 ]);
svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// color palette = one color per subgroup
const color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(subgroups)
    .range(['#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a'])

//stack the data? --> stack per subgroup
const stackedData = d3.stack()
    .keys(subgroups)
    (data)

// Show the bars
let bars = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(stackedData, d => d)

    bars.join(
    enter => {
        enter
        .append('g')
        .attr("fill", d => color(d.key))
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(d=>d)
        .attr("x", d => x(d.data.group))
        .attr("y", d => y(d[1]))
        .attr("height", d => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))
        .attr("width",x.bandwidth())
}, update => update, exit => exit.remove());
})
```

I only changed the code after //Show the bars

It works if instead of `join(enter=> enter)`

I only use `enter().append('g)`... etc.
I thought these are doing the same thing?

Lastly, I've been trying to draw everything from D3 directly. Is it stupid to do that yourself instead of using ready-made functions from places like Observable?
I want to learn, but I also want to be efficient.

thanks for any tips and help!

Comment: Your variable bars is about g elements, don't select rects on the enter part. You also bind the rect selection to the data but then you never add them to the chart (enter part). The update and exit part of the join will, once again, only deal with the g elements. Will not update the rects inside. Just do a join for the g elements and then a separate one for the rects.

Comment: Thank you @CarlosMoura I have been fairly confused about this I renamed this a couple of times, together with the excellent answer below I finally get what I was doing wrong.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to return the `enter` selection (you're using arrow function without returning anything from it)
2. You need to do `.join('rect')` after `selectAll('rect').data(d => d)` (if you don't join, nothing will be appended to the stack's `<g>`)

Here's the complete working solution (click the **Run code snippet** button below):

```js
const margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
const svg = d3
  .select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

// Parse the Data
d3.csv(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/data_stacked.csv"
).then(function(data) {
  // List of subgroups = header of the csv files = soil condition here
  const subgroups = data.columns.slice(1);

  // List of groups = species here = value of the first column called group -> I show them on the X axis
  const groups = data.map((d) => d.group);

  // Add X axis
  const x = d3.scaleBand().domain(groups).range([0, width]).padding([0.2]);
  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0));

  // Add Y axis
  const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 60]).range([height, 0]);
  svg.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // color palette = one color per subgroup
  const color = d3
    .scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(subgroups)
    .range(["#e41a1c", "#377eb8", "#4daf4a"]);

  //stack the data? --> stack per subgroup
  const stackedData = d3.stack().keys(subgroups)(data);

  // Show the bars
  let bars = svg
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(stackedData, (d) => d);

  bars.join(
    (enter) => {
      // don't forget to return the enter selection after appending 
      return enter
        .append("g")
        .attr("fill", (d) => color(d.key))
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data((d) => d)
        // don't forget to join 'rect'
        .join("rect")
        .attr("x", (d) => x(d.data.group))
        .attr("y", (d) => y(d[1]))
        .attr("height", (d) => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth());
    },
    (update) => update,
    (exit) => exit.remove()
  );
});
```

```html
<div id="chart"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.4.3/d3.min.js"></script>
```